# How to implement Java loop using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

```
// to search and delete
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='search']")).sendKeys("Diversification Rule Template"); 
driver.findElement(By.className("delete-template")).click(); 
Alert alert = driver.switchTo.alert(); 
Thread.sLeep(200); 
alert.accept(); 
String SuccessMessage = driver.findElement(By.className("toast")).getAttribute("class");
System.out.println("Message of Toast Message is: " n SuccessMessage);
Assert.assertEquals("toast toast-success", SuccessMessage);

// to search and delete
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='search']")).clear();
Thread.sLeep(200);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input(type='search']")).sendKeys("Diversification Rule Template2"); 
driver.findElement(By.className("delete-template")).click(); 
driver.switchTo().alert(); 
alert.accept(); 
String SuccessDeleteMessage = driver.findElement(By.className("toast")).getAttribute("class");
System.out.println("Message of Toast Message is: " SuccessDeleteMessage);
Assert.assertEquaLs("toast toast-success", SuccessDeleteMessage); 

// to search and delete
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='search']")).clear();
Thread.steep(200);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='search']")).sendKeys("New Diversification Rule");
driver.findElement(By.className("delete.template")).click();
driver.switchTo().alert(); 
alert.accept(); 
String SuccessDeleteMessage2 = driver.findElement(By.className("toast")).getAttribute("class");
System.out.println("Message of Toast Message is: SuccessDeleteMessage2);
```

I need to delete few users from the system and I don't want to repeat the process over again and again. So I want to implement loops that I can do it easily and having such a problem "element is not attached to the page document".  Any help would be great.

Comment: Is the javascript tag needed here?

Comment: yes @evolutionxbox

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you mean to ask about Java or JavaScript. May you clarify?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's a java script script alert that I want to using in java loop. Here I want to delete four user and I don't want to repeat my same code over again and again so I need to use loop.  and having such a problem "element is not attached to the page document" that I need to solve

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the search criteria. You do need to relocate the elements every time to avoid `StaleElementReferenceException`

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add("Diversification Rule Template");
    add("Diversification Rule Template2");
    add("New Diversification Rule");
}};

for (String name: names) {
    WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='search']"));
    searchField.clear();
    searchField.sendKeys(name);
    driver.findElement(By.className("delete-template")).click(); 
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo.alert(); 
    Thread.sLeep(200); 
    alert.accept(); 
    String SuccessMessage = driver.findElement(By.className("toast")).getAttribute("class");
    System.out.println("Message of Toast Message is: " n SuccessMessage);
    Assert.assertEquals("toast toast-success", SuccessMessage);
}
```